# Tell GCC to assume an object is initialized

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, uninitialized-constant

When compiling in GCC with `-Wall`, GCC will warn about using variables that might be uninitialized.  However, as the programmer, I know that a variable must be initialized if control enters a certain `if` statement:

```
int foo;

/* conditional assignment of foo goes here */

if (/* complicated condition that guarantees that foo has been initialized */){
    return test(foo);
}
```

In the above code, GCC will complain that `foo` may be used uninitialized.  In particular, the complain will arise from inside the definition of `test()`, where `foo` is actually used.

Is there a GCC builtin or equivalent to tell the compiler that `foo` is already initialized?  For example:

```
if (/* complicated condition that guarantees that foo has been initialized */){
    __assume_initialized(foo);
    return test(foo);
}
```

Note that placing `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"` before the line `return test(foo)` is insufficient as the uninitialized warning arises from the usage (e.g. comparison) of foo in the definition of `test()`, possibly in another compilation unit, where the pragma won't exist.

Neither do I want to put the pragma inside the definition of `test()`, because the issue is not with `test()`. `test()` should of course not be called with random garbage, and putting the pragma there might cause other mistakes to go unnoticed.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you know it will always be initialized in a conditional, remove the conditional?

Comment: Do you have a more complicated type than `int`? If not, can you just initialise it with some constant instead?

Comment: @viraptor It's actually a `class`, so I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: @Bernard: that should go into your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't understand what you mean.  The conditional is required because the return value should only be `test(foo)` under the circumstances where the conditional evaluates to true. Otherwise, some other value is returned.

Comment: Looks like an overenginnering concern and perhaps some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why can't you initialize that variable? What is the actual code doing? How large is the class of `foo` ? Did you benchmark that the initialization is harmful to performance?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah, perhaps it is overengineering.  The overhead is very small, and not noticeable to performance.

Comment: If the type is a class, then the compiler won't give you the warning. Constructor would be called. If the pointer is being used, just initialize with null, or use `unique_ptr`

Comment: _The complain will arise from inside the definition of `test()`_. Then it can't have anything to do with your `foo`. `test()` will only see the passed value, and not how it is (possibly uninitialized) passed. What is the exact case you have, and warning message?

Comment: @king_nak Recent versions of gcc are able to track an uninitialised variables through multiple scopes, function calls, and some collections.  You can get this warning "far" from the declaration of the supposedly uninitialised variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to (redundantly) initialize that variable e.g. by adding:

```
int foo=0;
```

the optimizing compiler (e.g. `g++ -O2`) is very likely to remove that initialization if it is unneeded. BTW, if the compiler don't optimize that in your particular case, the overhead of such an initialization is really small.

If `foo` is an instance of some `class` you could define a no-op constructor (perhaps a `private:` one) and make your function `friend` of that class.
If `foo` is some pointer initialize it to `nullptr`.

<sup>BTW, such an explicit initialization makes your code more *readable* and less brittle and perhaps even more [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) friendly. You might add a comment explaining why and how it might be unneeded. IMHO the readability increase is enough to justify such an initialization.</sup>

I tend to always initialize locals, leaving the compiler the opportunity to optimize away most of the useless initializations.

Alternatively (but I don't recommend that) use a [function specific pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html)  (as mentioned in your question) to disable such a warning.

Comment: After some experimentation with a similar issue, I am not sure the optimising statement is true.  Which makes sense if you reason backwards.  If a compiler is truly able to deduce the initialisation is unneeded because it's ultimately assigned, then it shouldn't report the variable is uninitialised.